# Can't get titlesec to format my sections properly

Tags: fontspec, titlesec

I'd like to use titlesec to format some custom section titles. Here's the code I came up with.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}

\titleformat{\section}{\sectionfont}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}

\begin{document}
\section*{David Krappenschitz}
\subsection*{Poop Research}

\end{document}
```

Since I have defined both `\sectionfont` and `\subsectionfont` to `Copperplate Gothic Bold`, I would expect both my section and subsection to render in that font. However, this is what I get:

[image]

`\section` seems to work fine, but `\subsection` is clearly in `Times New Roman`.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything right... What's missing here?

Comment: I believe you should use the starred form `\titleformat*`.

Comment: Could you take a look at my related question as well (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611019/titlesec-unexpected-labeling-behavior)?  Why does the starred form change the behavior like this? I thought the starred form mainly had an effect on the label... why is it affecting my fonts?

Comment: You are misunderstanding to which star the documentation refers. The macro `\titleformat` has a starred version which takes two arguments, and simply sets the font, or the unstarred version, which takes five arguments. The label is ignored if you use the starred version of the *sectioning* commands, not of `\titleformat`.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to achieve no label using only `titlesec` `titleformat` command as opposed to doing `\section*{Poop Research}`?

Answer (score 1):

No labels using `\titleformat` from the package`titlesec`.  Affects the whole document.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}


\titleformat{\section}{\sectionfont}{}{0pt}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}{}{0pt}{} 

\begin{document}
    \section{David Krappenschitz}
    \subsection{Poop Research}
    
\end{document}
```