# titlesec unexpected labeling behavior

Tags: titlesec

Regarding the `\titleformat` command, page 4 of the [titlesec manual](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) states:

> Both `<label>` and `<sep>` are ignored in starred versions of
> sectioning commands.

Which implies that no label should appear if the `\titleformat is starred`. I tried the following:

```
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}

\titleformat*{\section}{\sectionfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}

\begin{document}
\section{David Krappenschitz}
\subsection{Poop Research}

\end{document}
```

However this generates the following:

[image]

Why are the labels not being suppressed even though the documentation seems to state they should be?

Comment: I believe that the quoted text means that `<label>` and `<sep>` are ignored by `\section*{...}`, `\subsection*{...}`, etc.

Comment: See the first point in the same page, it says: "[T]he sectioning command to be redefined, i. e., \part, \chapter, \section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \paragraph or \subparagraph." This is a list of sectioning commands

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the manual. There is `\titleformat*`, but it's an “abbreviated form” of the full command `\titleformat`, where you just specify a single command, typically the font.

What the manual means is that `\section*` (or similar starred commands) will ignore the `<label>` and `<sep>` arguments.

If you want to just set the fonts and get no numbers, set a suitable value for `secnumdepth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate}

\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\sectionfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\sectionfont\bfseries}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
\section{David K}
\subsection{Research}

Text follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The starred versions of sectioning commands `\section` and `\subsection`
ignored the `label` and `sep` set by `\titleformat`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}

%%\titleformat*{\section}{\sectionfont}
%%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}

\titleformat{\section}{\sectionfont}{\Large \thesection }{20pt}{\large} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont}{\normalsize \thesection }{20pt}{\small} 

\begin{document}
    
    \section{David Krappenschitz 1}
    
    \subsection{Poop Research 1}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \section*{David Krappenschitz with *}
    
    \subsection*{Poop Research with *}
    
\end{document}
```